# R Shiny Modules

Tags: r, module, shiny

I'm trying to combine 2 examples from the gallery in the modules. the first works but the second gives an error: "character(0)"
if i change "breaks = as.numeric(input$n_breaks)" for "breaks = 30" it works.
For some reason fails to send input$n_breaks into function. 
What am I doing wrong? help, who knows, please.

my app.r:

```
library(shiny)

source("linked_scatter.R")
source("linked_hist.R")

ui <- navbarPage("Several modules",
             tabPanel("Modul_1",
                          h2("Module 1 example"),
                          linkedScatterUI("scatters"),
                          textOutput("summary")
                      ),
              tabPanel("Module_2",

                       h2("Module 2 example"),

                         linkedHistUI("histog")

                       )

              )




server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df <- callModule(linkedScatter, "scatters", reactive(mpg),
               left = reactive(c("cty", "hwy")),
               right = reactive(c("drv", "hwy"))
  )

  output$summary <- renderText({
    sprintf("%d observation(s) selected", nrow(dplyr::filter(df(),     selected_)))
  })

 df2 <- callModule(linkedHist, "histog")



}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

my linked_hist.r

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

linkedHistUI <- function(id) {
ns <- NS(id)

fluidPage(


    mainPanel(

      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput(inputId = "n_breaks",
                    label = "Number of bins in histogram (approximate):",
                    choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50),
                    selected = 20)
      ),

      plotOutput(outputId = ns("main_plot"), height = "300px")

      )  
    )


}

linkedHist <- function(input, output, session) {


  output$main_plot <- renderPlot({hist(faithful$eruptions,
       probability = TRUE,
       breaks = as.numeric(input$n_breaks),
       #breaks = 30, 
       xlab = "Duration (minutes)",
       main = "Geyser eruption duration")
  })

}
```

Comment: I haven't tried running your code, but I can immediately spot something that triggers a red flag. Your `inputId = "n_breaks"` should probably be wrapped in `ns()` like so: `inputId = ns("n_breaks")`.  This `NS()` and `ns()` functions are the most important thing in modules. Any inputs you define inside a module should namespace their ids

Comment: daattali , thank you!!!